# PHP: Get City via IP address

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping

Ok, so I looked into finding IP address and scraping so I needed a way to get the city of who ever entered my website and it would view a certain data.

Any Idea of what I did wrong, for now i only need it to echo the city

So here is my Code

```
//Reach Site

$ipsite=file_get_contents("http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

//Scrape City

preg_match("/<th>City:</th><td>(.*?)</s", $ipsite, $ipcity);

//echo city

echo($ipcity[1]);
```

Thanks alot

Comment: I might be wrong, but you should probably add the multiline modifier: `/<th>City:</th><td>(.*?)</sm`

Comment: You should enable `error_reporting`. The regex is wrong. And they'll likely block your request (ToS: http://whatismyipaddress.com/api).

Comment: what you did wrong is trying to parse html with regexes, and also assume that the url will always return what you want.

Comment: Question is violating the TOS of a third-party-side.

Comment: Notice: You cannot always get the correct city only from the IP address. (at least in Germany)

Comment: Use the API outlined by @mario, following the described conditions and stop querying websites designed for "humans".

Comment: @mario The API is only for fetching YOUR Ip-Adress, i.e. open `http://ipv4bot.whatismyipaddress.com` The fetching of the *city* is strictly prohibited: *We do not provide API access to any of the geolocation data ... Feel free to link to http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/xx.xx.xx.xx from your website or application ... please do not attempt scripted access.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use this sites API to get the location.

[ipinfo](http://ipinfo.io/)

You can do this with PHP the following way.

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
echo $result->city;
```

Comment: thanks i'll use this :)